# Is this really considered an object? From c++ book

Tags: c++

[Picture of text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwQrK.png)

> To read something, we need somewhere to read into; that is, we need somewhere in the computer's memory to place what we read. We call such a "place" an object. An *object* is a region of memory with a *type* that specifies what kind of information can be placed in it. A named object is called a *variable*. For example, character strings are put into `string` variables and integers are put into `int` variables. You can think of an object as a "box" into which you can put a value of the object's type

An object is a region of memory with a type that specifies what kind of information can be placed in it? Here they give an example with ints and strings which are like built in datatypes, I already know some oop so I was kinda confused because like I thought an object was kinda its own separate entity with its own user created datatype? I get that all objects have their own region of memory but they're basically calling a variable of type int, age, with the value 42 an object. Is this correct?

Comment: In a language like Java, would you not call the `int` an object because it's not user created? One could argue that the book's usage is a tad wide, while yours is a tad narrow.

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text. Also, when quoting text, give proper attribution to the actual author! As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Um my bad this is from Bjarne Stroustrup's Programming Principles and Practice using C++

Comment: Yes, it is correct. In C++, the word "object" does not mean "instance of a class type". This is the definition of what the word "object" means in C++. Words can have different meanings in different contexts.

Comment: There are no languages that I'm aware of where only instances of user-created types are called "objects". Do you have an example?

Comment: I believe, this isn't an object like in OOP. This term is used in C++ specific sense. It is referred here and there, e.g. in so-called [aliasing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7005988/7478597) which say that two pointers of different type may not address the same object (with only few exceptions) -- very roughly spoken.

Comment: @eerorika in Java, `String` is not user defined, similarly `list` in Python, or `Array` in JavaScript

Comment: @Caleth Hmm, I was wrong about Python and JS. Even classes are objects (not just instances of classes) in those languages. In Java, String is a class.

Comment: In C++, "object" is a compiler-writer's term.

Comment: @eerorika but `String` is not defined by the user, it is defined by the language. And there's the instances of `Class` that denote `String` et al

Answer (score 5):

This is the wording from the C++ standard [[intro.object]](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#:object_model):

> The constructs in a C++ program create, destroy, refer to, access, and
> manipulate objects. An object is created by a definition, by a
> new-expression ([expr.new]), by an operation that implicitly creates
> objects (see below), when implicitly changing the active member of a
> union, or when a temporary object is created ([conv.rval],
> [class.temporary]). An object occupies a region of storage in its
> period of construction ([class.cdtor]), throughout its lifetime, and
> in its period of destruction ([class.cdtor]).

There is more to read about objects, I just picked this paragraph from the intro so you can see that the term "object" in C++ is more general than "instance of a user defined class". Note how the last sentence is quite similar with what Bjarne wrote in the book. What you refer to (instance of a class) is called "class object".

A perhaps more readable introduction to objects in C++ can be found here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object.

PS: I am not a historian, but I suppose that the term "object" was already in wide-spread use before Object Orientation came into existance. There have been objects before. They were not invented by OOP, just put into the focus. Also note that C++ is not a (pure) OOP language, but rather multi-paradigm.

Answer (score 2):

> but they're basically calling a variable of type int, age, with the value 42 an object. Is this correct?

They're correct.

> I already know some oop

Modern OOP nomenclature is different from nomenclature of C++.

> and strings which are like built in datatypes

The `std::string` type is a class i.e. a "user defined" data type (although it is provided by the standard library).

Comment: Modern OOP nomenclature isn't really based on Java.   Most Java nomenclature is based on Java designers and/or Java programmers interpretation of OOP nomenclature (it's debatable in a number of cases whether or not Java nomenclature is consistent with modern OOP nomenclature).

Comment: @Peter Fair enough. I've just noticed that they correlate closely and made an assumption.